# Best Practice to generate uuid ? php OR MySql

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, uuid

What is the best practices to generate UUID (PRIMARY KEY)
let it generate at Mysql end OR
let it generate at PHP end

doing some performances test i find generating it at php end is a bit faster

but doing some Google i find many are practicing it to generate at MySQL end
http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram

so what would be the right way to do so for an continuously growing data ?

Comment: No expert, but if I use `UUID` or `GUID` I do it for scenarios, where I need an ID, before I interact with the Database. If I need the ID after interaction with a Database, I have had never problems in using a simple AutoIncrement ID. Thats is my practise, for sure not the best.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt sometime i feel the same sticking to primary is the best way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to insert rows from different applications then generating the UID via the DB is the *safest* method because the implementation is centralised and of course won't change between applications.

Let's say you decide to create an API in another language. You would then need to implement the same generator in that language. There might be differences in the way this other language implements functions you rely on to generate key data, which lead to duplicate keys.

If you are only going to be inserting rows from PHP on your own server, it doesn't matter if you generate UIDs in the application or the DB.

*Safe* isn't always *right*. Or practical. Weigh up the pros and cons of your intended use cases and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

you could try a very good PHP class [Pure PHP UUID Generator](https://gist.github.com/dahnielson/508447)

- Clone repository (Or copy past the UUID.php class into your php file..)
- Use the class with static method directly

Example:

`UUID::v5('1546058f-5a25-4334-85ae-e68f2a44bbaf', 'SomeRandomString');`

Comment: ..and use `UUID::v4()` to generate your initial namespace UUID

Comment: @Jacky Attias i did not use that one but used this one https://github.com/ramsey/uuid which is some what similar to that and tested it works good , but still the question remains unanswered that why in php and not in MySQL or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Using native database UUID functions will probably cause problems if the database is replicated.  At the same time I would confirm that any pre-written UUID generators used be tested to confirm the that the least significant byte of the UUID changes faster than most significant byte (to accommodate database index clustering).